# System.Windows.Control.DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using below `DataGrid` in my C# WPF code. This `DataGrid` populated by csv file, I have written a csv loader which reads and populates `DataGridRows` is in tab (say tab1) when I open another tab and come back to this original tab which contains grid and filled data after upload, **the rows of `DataGrid` are gone. I want to prevent this.**

```
<DataGrid
   SelectionMode="Extended" 
   SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
   Focusable="True"  
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
   MaxHeight="710"    
   Height="Auto"
   Width="Auto"
   EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
   VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true"
   VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
   ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="false" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridRows}" 
   Margin="1,6,0,10"
   Name="dataGrid" 
   RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
   IsReadOnly="True"
   FontFamily="Calibri" 
   FontSize="13" 
   DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fill the DataGridRows manually you shouldn't be setting a ItemSource, just erase

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridRows}"
```

If you want your DataGrid to be binded to that source check that the DataContext isn't null.